# Find the power series for $f(x) = \frac{\cos(x^3)}{2x^2}$

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I'm pretty sure if it were just $\cos(x^3)$ i could subsititue $x^3$ for $x$, everywhere in the known series, but what do I do because it's divided by $2x^2$?

Comment: Divide it (the series) by $2x^2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We know that
$$\cos x=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\dfrac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$
Substitute $x\to x^3$, and divide by $2x^2$ to get (Note that the term $2x^2$ has no dependence on $k$)
$$\dfrac{\cos(x^3)}{2x^2}=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\dfrac{(-1)^kx^{6k-2}}{2(2k)!}$$

Answer (score 2):

You were close. Just divide the resulting sequence by $2x^2$ to get
$$
\frac1{2x^2}-\frac{x^6}{2\cdot 2 x^2}+\dots 
$$